# Troubleshooting Biber warnings

Tags: biber

I have a huge bib file that I try my damnedest to keep clean. Now I found that running biber on a tex file which uses it produces these warnings

```
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: warning: comma(s) at end of name (removing)
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: author, warning: comma(s) at end of name (removing)
```

but I have no idea which line among the 4000 that I have produce this warning. Is there a way to have biber output line numbers or other information that can help find the source of these warnings?

Comment: Just search for `, and` or `,and` or `,}` or `, }` and may be you will be lucky

Comment: Thanks! I did search for `,}` and `, }` but I didn't know that `, and` is also problematic. Now I have a warning free bib file :) .

Comment: Welcome @Tohiko ... Happy TeXing

Comment: @koleygr Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so the question can be marked as solved?

Comment: Thanks @moewe ... done....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for

`,}` and `, }` or

`,and` and `, and`

could help...

These are problematic inputs inside author's fields.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue that the biber devs probably won't fix, see [#60 in their bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/60).

What I use to find those problematic places is:

```bash
grep -nP '(?:author|editor)\s*=.*,\s*(?:and\b|})' *.bib
```

This looks for any lines that

- contain `author =` or `editor =` and
- contain a comma followed by `and` or a closing brace `}`.

However, this will fail on multi-line fields. So if you don't find all occurences with the above command, you might want to try

```bash
grep -nP ',\s*(?:and\b|})' *.bib
```

although that outputs many other fields, such as lists in abstracts which are actually not problematic.